# How to write do while loop in Latex?

Tags: latex, do-while, pseudocode

I've written the code, but line number are not proper, the code looks like this:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\REQUIRE $Graph\ G(V, E)$

\STATE $\textbf{\textit{function}}\ $
  \Do
    \State Something
  \doWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\label{algo1}
\end{algorithm}
```

The output of above code looks like this:

[image]

How I can get the proper numbering? Or is there any simpler way to write do while loop in latex?

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try the `algorithm2e` package. ;)

[image: preview]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[norelsize, linesnumbered, ruled, lined, boxed, commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \SetAlgoLined
 \LinesNumbered
 \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
 \Input{$Graph\ G(V, E)$}
 \SetKwProg{Function}{function}{}{end}
 \SetKwRepeat{Do}{do}{while}
 \Function{function(param: int) : int}{
     \Do{done = false}{ something }
 }
 \caption{Algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```